# How create a permanent notification with battery level?

Tags: android, statusbar, android-notifications, batterylevel, permanent

Is possible create a permanent notification of battery level starting from this code?:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.registerReceiver(this.myBatteryReceiver , new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    ...
}

private BroadcastReceiver myBatteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        //here you can use level as you wish.
    }
};
```

And this is an example of a notification.

```
private void CheckNoti(){ 
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                                service.this);
                notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Context");
                notificationBuilder.setTicker("TickerText");
                notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_icon);

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, service.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                notificationIntent, 0);

                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

                notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

                mNotificationManager.notify(1,
                                notificationBuilder.build());
    }   }
```

I have to create a permanent notification with the battery level if possible. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use the ongoing flags : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing%28boolean%29

The user will not be able to cancel the notification so please don't forget to remove it when it's not useful anymore.

For toggle in it, you need to add a [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) or a [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) to your app. Then add a checkboxPreference : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

In your code, you can now toggle this particular setting :

```
boolean permanent = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("permanent", false);
if(permanent) {
    notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
}
```

Comment: In many application i see the possibility to remove the notification or not.. why? How can i do something like that? A simple checkbox "Show notification" check yes, uncheck no..

Comment: I edited my question. You'll need to recreate the notification and use ongoing or not in function of what the users chose.

Comment: is possbile do it only for a "text" notification or also a notification that show the battery percentage with a broadcastreceiver?

Comment: For any notification.

Comment: so inside the `onReceive` i can put the notification code right?

Comment: Just try it, and you'll see by yourself.

Comment: Have i to call the notification in the onCreate?

Comment: You can use tutorial like this one : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html to know how to use notification.